# Hyper-V Default Switch DHCP long lease time

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dhcp, hyper-v

I need to create VMs (on Windows 10 and 11) that can talk to each other, and to the public internet. The machines on which I need to do  this may have Docker Desktop for Windows and WSL2 installed. Anything I do cannot interfere with those.

So I create the VMs using Hyper-V, and connect them to the "Default Switch". This works fine. The problem is that IP addresses assigned to my VMs by built-in DHCP *may* change whenever I reboot the VMS. Sometimes they do, sometimes they don't.

I need the VMs to retain their IP address leases for a long time, say 10-15 days. The guest operating systems are either Debian or Alpine Linux. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Creating a new switch and a new NetNAT is not an option, as that interferes with Docker for Windows. Static IP addresses can be an option, provided I can still connect from the VMs to the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hyper-V default Switch is not modifiable at all, as far as I know.

You could try to give the VMs static IP addresses from the end of the
IP range, which is normally `192.168.0.0–192.168.255.255` or
`172.17.0.0–172.31.255.255`, based on the host system IP address
and its built-in local collision detection mechanism to determine
if an IP address in these ranges is already assigned to a
network interface on the local host system.

The IPs from the end of the range might never be needed to be allocated,
or Hyper-V might be clever enough to avoid collisions.

---

If the above doesn't help, try also to set the MAC address of the
VM to be static.

This is done in VM
*Settings > Hardware > Network Adapter > Advanced Features >
MAC address*, and set its value to "Static".

---

As a last resort, you could try to install an additional virtualization product that does not conflict with Hyper-V.
VirtualBox is
[said](https://us.informatiweb.net/tutorials/it/virtualization/virtualbox-use-virtualbox-and-hyper-v-at-the-same-time.ht)
to be able to coexist with Hyper-V, but this needs to be verified by
testing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have already tried both your suggestions. The static IP from end of range idea is not guaranteed to work, because the Hyper-V DHCP does not assign IP addresses in strict sequence, and is not clever enough to avoid collisions.

VirtualBox does indeed coexist with Hyper-V. But you cannot use VirtualBox guest additions, and the resulting VMs run much slower, 

I guess what I am looking for is guest OS settings which can make the DHCP lease persist through VM reboots, for a number of days.

Comment: (1) Have you in VM *Settings > Hardware > Network Adapter > Advanced Features > MAC address* set it to "Static"? (2) See also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1536052/8672) for ensuring that the default switch will always have the same IP. (3) The [hyperv2hosts project](https://github.com/aaalgo/hyperv2hosts) might be useful.

Comment: I hadn't tried "Static" MAC addresses! I think this will solve my problem. Thank you very much.

I'm new to SuperUser. Can I mark your comment as the solution?